# Access to page's photo albums from within web app using tokens?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, sdk, token

Im using Facebook's PHP sdk for the first time in a clients site and I'm a little confused. I'm trying to get some data from the clients facebook page and inject it into their site. One of the objects I am trying to get is a list of the clients photo albums for a photo gallery.

```
<?php 
$albums = $Facebook->api("/169639127532/albums?fields=id,name,cover_photo");
$photos = array();
$queries = array();
foreach($albums['data'] as $album) {
    if(array_key_exists("cover_photo", $album)) 
    $queries[] = array("method" => "GET", "relative_url" =>     "/".$album['cover_photo']."?fields=source");
}

$rawPhotos = $Facebook->api('?batch='.json_encode($queries), 'POST');
foreach($rawPhotos as $photo) {
    //print_r(json_decode($photo['body'])); echo "<br /><br />";
    $photo = json_decode($photo['body']);
    $photos[$photo->id] = $photo->source;
}
```

As you can see, im getting a list of the albums, then using a batch request to get all the cover photos for those albums.

Using my clients page ID, this doesn't work, nothing is returned. However if I use another page's ID this works.

So I put this down to authorisation. I noticed that if I used the Graph API explorer with an access token I could get the photos. Because of this, I copied the Token I had generated with the API explorer, and set it globally on the site using the following function and this works.

```
$Facebook->setAccessToken($token)
```

Obivously this isn't a very robust solution as the tokens only exist for a finite amount of time. I tried getting a token for the app using the /oauth/access_token API call with my apps details and successfully got a token back. If I use this as the token I can no longer see the data I was getting with the temporary token from the graph explorer however.

I do not want users to have to login just in order to see the photo gallery on the site.

How do I go about getting a token for the app that would allow me to do this?

Thanks.